# How to hide this image behind it's container?

Tags: html, css

To have a responsive design, I made this `<img>` to have `max-width:37%;`. But when I open the jsFiddle window far enough to make it wide enough, the image extends over it's containers size and won't fit anymore.

This is a screenshot I made:

[image]

But I want the overlapping sides not to be shown, like this (photo edited):

[image]

If you want to see it in action, [use my fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zk755cr9/29/).

The image should not be seen further than the boundaries of its containers are. **How can I prevent that the image is bigger than its container?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume that you want the entire image to stay visible. So, you need to set the `max-height` property to `100%`.

```
.mbox img {
    max-height: 100%;
    max-width: 37%;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zk755cr9/31/).

**Update**: Since you want the image to keep the `max-width:37%` you need to hide the overflown part.

I added a `div` that wraps the `div.mbox_content` and the `img`. I gave to this div the class `mbox_wrapper`. You also need to add the `z-index:2` property to the `<h2>`.

```
.mbox_wrapper {
    overflow:hidden;  
    position:relative;
}

.mbox h2 {
    z-index:2;
}
```

Here is an updated [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zk755cr9/36/).

Comment: It's an "ok" solution, but not as I meant it: Stretch it open to a 1920px wide screen: Now the image is a bit small. After opening the box, the image resizes itself to fit to max-width. The image is moving. I just wanted it to be "not visible where the box ends". :)

Comment: You mean that you want in a 1920px width, the user to view a part of the image?

Comment: Nonono. The user should just be `max-width:37%`, which is the width of "the box where the image is in". Now if the image's length is MORE than the box is high in closed state, then this overlapping image just should be cut.

Comment: I've added an additional image (MS.Paint edited) to clarify. :)

Comment: Thanks, it is pretty clear now, I updated my answer!

Comment: Was to say about `z-index:2`, but you did it. Well, now it's pretty clear: You're the winner, it works perfectly. Thanks for your effort! :)

Comment: @Trollwut I would use the `@media` CSS rule to change element sizes based on screen size. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Answer (score 1):

Just need to change the z-index property

Answer (score 0):

you need to apply a max-height tag to the css..
Then the image won't be able to exceed the height of the containing div.

```
max-height: 100%;
```

Comment: As I already commented Tasos: That would be "ok". But if you have a wider screen, the image at closed state is small and then resizes to max-width when opening the box. I just wanted the image to stay as it is, but not be visible where it is larger than the borders.